# Android inflate and Async Task

Tags: android, inflate

I have a layout file. It needs to inflate in Async thread, and then it needs to be sent to the main thread display. But if I inflate it immediately after Activity created. It has the error: inflateexception.

If I inflate it in main thread once and then inflate in Async thread. It does not have the error.

This is my code 
Inflate code:

```
View vwDragMainOrder = layoutInflate.inflate(
R.layout.pop_drag_mainorder, null);
```

layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/et_pop_drag_mainorder_exceptiontypegroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/et_pop_drag_mainorder_batch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Batch goods"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/et_pop_drag_mainorder_unshippedoffload"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="goods not put in storage "
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/et_pop_drag_mainorder_shippedoffload"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Already out kula cargo"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_pop_drag_mainorder_pcsremark"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Number note"
            android:textSize="22dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_pop_drag_mainorder_pcsremark"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_pop_drag_mainorder_remark"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="remark"
            android:textSize="22dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_pop_drag_mainorder_remark"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_pop_drag_mainorder_exception"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Exception "
            android:textSize="22dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_pop_drag_mainorder_exception"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What message does the exception give?

Comment: Why is it necessary to inflate in a separate thread?